# Why doesn't Cheese not allow for multiple effects to be selected at the same time?

Tags: cheese

For some reason in cheese on my 12.10 Ubuntu box, it seems I can not choose multiple effects. Is this a bug or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way it is designed to work. Cheese at one time *could* use multiple effects at once, but ever since it changed to the new effects framework, that has no longer been possible.

Comment: No way to reenable it? Like a patch?

Comment: @PyRulez are you going to write it ;)?